# Python SymPy addition of two expressions

Tags: python, error-handling, sympy

I have a two simple expressions (M1 and M2) in `Python SymPy`.
However, when I try to add these two expressions, I get the following error:

> "TypeError: cannot add <class 'sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix'> and <class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'>"

How can I add the expressions M1 and M2 without encountering this error?

MWE:

```
from sympy import *
t, alpha, b1, b2, x1, x2 = symbols('t alpha beta1 beta2 X1 X2')

beta = Matrix([[b1, b2]]).T
X = Matrix([[x1, x2]]).T

M1 = t*alpha**2
M2 = X.T * (t*beta*beta.T) * X

M1 + M2 # Here I get the corresponding error
```

Comment: `M1` is an `Mul` expression, multiplying 2 'scalar' symbols.  `M2` is created from `Matrix` objects.  Have you studied the `Matrix` documentation to see what kinds of addition a possible?

Comment: You should use `MatrixSymbol` to create a symbol that represents a matrix. Otherwise adding a scalar and a matrix will give the error you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M2` has a shape of (1, 1), but it's still considered a matrix and it seems addition between matrices and a scalar isn't supported. From a [github issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/5205) from 10 years ago:

> We've already discussed scalar addition in issue 5369 and we decided not to support it, so this isn't going to happen either, unless we revert that decision.

[Link](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/5369) to referenced issue.

However, you can do

```
M1 + M2[0]      # this will be a scalar
```

or, if you want everything in matrix form, i.e., add a scalar elementwise

```
M1 * ones(M2.rows, M2.cols) + M2
```